# What is the purpose of the diamond mark printed in surah Yusuf verse 11?

Tags: quran-recitation, tajweed

What is the purpose of the diamond mark printed in surah Yusuf verse 11?

[image]

Comment: This is already covered in [Examples of quran verses that differ from normal recitation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/41365/examples-of-quran-verses-that-differ-from-normal-recitation/41376#41376)